# Canvas.ToBlob not returning valid PNG?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to save canvas.toBlob output in a PNG file, but the output does not seem like valid PNG (although it's close).The 1st 4 bytes should be (hex) "89 50 4e 47". Instead I'm getting "ff fd 50 4e 47", i.e. instead of "89" it's "ff fd". When I try to open the PNG file, apps like Paint say it's not valid. Sample below shows formatting of output to console, but not saving the file.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillRect(25, 25, 100, 100);     

canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener('loadend', (e) => {
        var result = e.srcElement.result;
        var hex = StrToHex(result);
        console.log(`result=${result}`);
        console.log(`hex=${hex}`);
    });
    reader.readAsText(blob);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[FileReader.readAsText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsText) without an encoding parameter will read your Blob with an `UTF-8` encoding.

That is, the bytes `89 50 4e 47` become the string `�PNG`. What you are doing here, is to get the hex from this string, which is not the same as the original byte value:

```js
// build a Blob from this hex string
const originalStrHex = '89 50 4e 47';
const hexAsUint8 = originalStrHex
  .split(' ')
  .map((v) => parseInt(v, 16));
const bytes= Uint8Array.from(hexAsUint8);
const reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsText(new Blob([bytes]));
reader.onload = e => {
  const res = reader.result;
  console.log(res);
  const fromUTF8 = new TextEncoder().encode(res);
  const strHex = [...fromUTF8]
    .map(v => v.toString(16).padStart(2, "0"))
    .join(' ');
  // if that was correct, we should have had the same as originalStrHex
  console.log(strHex);
};
```

So, mot probably, your Blob is correct.
What you want is simply to [read it as an ArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsArrayBuffer) rather than as a UTF-8 string:

```js
document.createElement('canvas').toBlob(handleBlob);

function handleBlob(fullblob) {
  const blob = fullblob.slice(0, 4);
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = e => {
    const view = new Uint8Array(reader.result);
    const strHex = [...view].map(v => v.toString(16).padStart(2, "0")).join(' ');
    console.log(strHex);
  };
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
}
```

Comment: Wow - that's great. Thanks so much for the detailed help!